# Mortgage formula give result not a number (nan) when 30 years is passed to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on mortguage calculator and facing problem when the years value get bigger than it give me infinity in console and nan in result.

```js
    // principle / initial amount borrowed
    var p = housePriceValue; 

    // calculate interest rate final value

    var interestRateValueByAnum = interestRateValue / 12
    var interestRateValuePercentByMonth = interestRateValueByAnum / 100 
    var i = interestRateValuePercentByMonth.toFixed(4)

    var n =  numberOfYears * 12
    fha.value = p * i * (Math.pow(1 + i, n)) / (Math.pow(1 + i, n) - 1)
```

Comment: `i` is a string, so `1 + i` gives unexpected results.  Get rid of `.toFixed(4)`.

Comment: Thanks  James now i understood the tofixed() convert to string the result after round up